# Angular, JWTs and 3rd party auth

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I'm not posting any code here as I have a design problem. It may also be that I'm trying to do something that makes no sense - if so, let me know.

I have an Angular site that uses JWTs. At present I use Passport.js with a LocalStrategy. I would like to use Twitter login. I can't work out how to handle the communications.

The Passport docs envisage a situation where you go to a route on your server that redirects you to Twitter and Twitter calls back your server after it has finished, and then your server can respond to this second request (I think) with a new page and a cookie.

But I have Angular on the client side, and I can't find any tutorials for handling that. I think I could get Angular to open a window and connect to Twitter, and then I presume twitter could callback my server, but how then does my server find the Angular client to send the JWT?

Answer (score 2):

I had a project that I needed to implement Facebook, Twitter and Local logins. With passport Facebook and Local were easy but with Twitter I just gave up and implemented it without passport.

I just used the Twitter API.

Very helpful was the documentation on [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer). It is an angular library for handle the login types in the front end, but it also have a very nice examples how to handle the logins in the different back end languages without using any third party libraries. I actually haven't used it, because I wrote all I needed myself without any third party libraries, but it helped me understand better different login APIs and how to handle them in the backend. You can check the examples [here](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer/tree/master/examples/server).

Hope this helps you.